# Finding the minimum value of an integral using least squares-mean function approximation

Tags: analysis, polynomials, orthogonality, least-squares, orthogonal-polynomials

I am starting to study some concepts related to orthogonal polynomials and my teacher told me to prove the following theorem,

**Theorem**
The integral $\int_{a}^{b} Q_n^2(x)w(x) dx$ where $Q_n(x)$ is any monic polynomial of degree $n$, takes its minimum value when $Q_n(x)=P_n(x)$, where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ associated to a weight function $w(x)$ such that $\{P_n\}$ is an orthogonal sequence associated to $w(x)$.

My first idea was to maybe use the Least-squares function approximation that my teacher has in the slides, that says the following:
The integral $\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-p(x)|^2w(x) dx$ takes the minimum value when $p(x)=a_0p_0(x)+...+a_n p_n(x)$ where $a_m= \int_a^bf(x)p_n(x)w(x) dx$.

So, i thought of the following approach:
If I take $p(x)$ to be $Q_n(x)$ in the Least-squares function approximation  i presented above, i would see that when i calculate the $a_m$ coefficients all of them would be zero except for $a_n$ which i would then have to verify to be 1 and then we would have that $Q_n(x)=P_n(x)$.

Is my thought process correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What is $P_n$ ? What is $w(x)$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe according to what i studied in class $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ associated to a weight function $w(x)>0$.

Comment: Hint. 

Supposing $Q_n=\sum_ka_kP_n$ we have

$$
\int\left(\sum_k^na_kP_n\right)^2w dx = \sum_k^na_k^2
$$

and obviously $a_n^2\le \sum_k^na_k^2$

Comment: @Cesareo Sorry to bother, but i have reached the previous equality, but how does that allow me conclude that integral hits its minimum value when $Q_n(x)=P_n(x)$
? It seems that will lead me to make conclusions about the integral value, no?

Comment: I suppose that the polynomial basis $P_k,\{k=1,\cdots,n\}$ is orthonormal which means that $\int P_jP_k w dx = \delta_{j,k}$. Now $Q_n$ should contain $P_n$ in it's expansion. Then $Q_n$ expansion will minimize the integral when $Q_n = a_n P_n$

Comment: @Cesareo I was thinking that I could look at the inequality $a_n^2 \leq \sum_k^n a_k^2$ and notice that the equality holds if and only if $a_0=a_1=...=a_{n-1}=0$. Therefore, we would have $Q_n=a_n P_n(x)$. Now, to find $a_n$ (which should be 1) does it suffices to find it using the formula $a_n=\int_a^b f(x)p_n(x)w(x) dx$ that i gave before? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: $a_n$ is undecidable. It can assume any real number $\ne 0$.